# Write tar.gz folder in R

Tags: r, directory, tar

I would like to know how I can tar.gz a folder to a specific location

I have tried this command line:

```
system(paste('tar -czf', "LC82180762013109-SC20161023011402.tar.gz", srdir,' -C ', outdir))
```

where `srdir` is the path to the folder I want to tar.gz

```
> srdir
[1] "/tmp/RtmpJrOTKW/raster/LT52180761985144-SC20161030213413"
```

and `outdir` is the path to where I want to store the tar.gz file

```
> outdir
[1] "/media/simonbesnard/Hard_Drive_SB/SimonBesnard/PhD_MPI/RO1/Inputs/Landsat_Flux_Site/BR-Afs"
```

The tar.gz file should look like LT52180761985144-SC20161030213413.tar.gz

Other alternative but also does not work:

```
system(paste('find', srdir, '-maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -exec tar cvf {}.tar.gz -C', outdir, '. ;'))
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [the `tar()` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/tar.html)?

Comment: Not yet. How would you suggest to do it with the tar function?

Comment: Probably something like `setwd(outdir); tar("LC8.tar.gz", files=srdir, compression="gzip")`. [`?tar`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/tar.html) is relatively straight-forward. Heck, you could even do `withr::with_dir(outdir, tar("LC8.tar.gz", files=srdir, compression="gzip"))`. Either way, I often find R's `system` and `system2` commands rather direct yet naive; look for `utils::*` functions like this one.